# How to perform repeat padding in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have variable length data and want to pack it to batches with the size of max sample len in batch by repeating shorter samples.

For example from this

`[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3]]`

make this

`[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2, 2]]`

Comment: [mre]? tried anything?

Comment: data is a numpy.array or a  python list ?

Answer (score 4):

not a `numpy` answer, but you can do that using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

lst = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3]]

n = max(len(item) for item in lst)
res = list(list(islice(cycle(item), n)) for item in lst)
print(res)  # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1], [2, 2, 3, 2, 2]]
```

where i use [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle over the sublists and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the first `n` elements.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3]]
max_len = max(map(len, data))
result = np.array([[row[i % len(row)] for i in range(max_len)] for row in data])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 0 1]
 [2 2 3 2 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [np.resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html):

```
from itertools import starmap

data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3]]
m = len(max(data, key=len))
r = np.array(list(starmap(np.resize, ((e, m) for e in data))))
print(r)
```

output:

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 0 1]
 [2 2 3 2 2]]
```

---

here is a simple benchmark with the proposed solutions:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle, islice
from random import randint, sample
from itertools import starmap


from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder
b = BenchmarkBuilder()

@b.add_function()
def hiroprotagonist(lst):
    n = max(len(item) for item in lst)
    res = list(list(islice(cycle(item), n)) for item in lst)
    np.array(res)

@b.add_function()
def kederrac(data):

    m = len(max(data, key=len))
    r = np.array(list(starmap(np.resize, ((e, m) for e in data))))

@b.add_function()
def DaniMesejo(data):

    max_len = max(map(len, data))
    result = np.array([[row[i % len(row)] for i in range(max_len)] for row in data])


@b.add_arguments('Number of sublists')
def argument_provider():
    for exp in range(2, 14):
        size = 2**exp
        yield size, [sample(range(size),  randint(1, min(1000, size))) for _ in range(size)]

r = b.run()
r.plot()
```

Comment: This is a clever use of `resize`, but since it has to convert each `e` to an array, it will be slower than the answer that uses `itertools.chain`.  The two answers may scale differently, especially if the inner lists are long and widely varied in length.

Comment: @hpaulj as far as I can see, the other solutions are creating new lists, it is not the same?

Comment: also in my benchmark, it shows that np.resize is better for  a high number of inner sublists